# What actually serializer's create method's validated_data arg contains in Django RestFramework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am creating a rest api. I have a custom user and also serializer to deserialize the incoming data and save it to the database. And actually a succeeded in that but I have a doubt. Please go through the code 
I am only providing here the code of custom user model, for brevity

```
# use AbstractUser if wants already exists fields Of 
# django default User otherwise use AbstractBaseUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    
    objects = UserManager()

    # use email fields to login
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []        # there's no required fields
     
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

View handling the request

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def registerUser(request):

    serialized = CustomUserSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serialized.is_valid():
        serialized.save()
        return Response({"status": 200})
    
    else:
        return Response({"status": 500, "errors": serialized.errors})
```

Serializer code

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

UserModel = get_user_model()

class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ['id', 'password', 'email']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = UserModel.objects.create_user(
                                    email=validated_data['email'], 
                                    password=validated_data['password'])
        return user
```

Now back to the main doubt which I have 
The code provided above run without any errors but an error pop up when I do this

> password = validated_data['pass']

I also change the JSON when doing this

```
{
  "email": "user123@maid.com",
  "pass" : "lovetobemaid"
}
```

**So it only work with password key**
**So the doubt is validated_data have the json passed key-value or something else**